# Converting an NFO to PNG with Python and PIL

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an NFO file with some crazy high ASCII arts using a Python script and PIL. Everything is nice when the NFO contains just simple characters, but with the "full rectangles" arts all i get is a lot of "ùùùù".

```
nfoFont = ImageFont.truetype('cour.ttf', size=12, encoding='unic')

#[...other code...]

nfoImage = Image.new("RGB", nfoSize, 'black')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(nfoImage)
currentLineHeight = 0;
for line in nfoText:
    draw.text((0, currentLineHeight), line, font=nfoFont, fill='gray')
    currentLineHeight += nfoFontHeight
```

I think i'm probably using the wrong font, and the wrong encoding. I know this kind of NFOs were created with CP437 encoding, but i can't see a way to obtain this.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get the contents of the nfoText variable? Is it a unicode or byte string?

Without knowing how PIL handles encodings, I'm assuming it works correctly with Unicode strings, then just read the nfo file with:

```
import codecs
nfoText = codecs.open('something.nfo', 'r', 'cp437').read()
```

I can't check right now if Python supports the cp437 encoding, and I don't have an nfo file available (I've only seen them used in pirated software, but or course I assume that you have a legitimate reason to handle them). Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: I get the contents of nfoText just open() - ing the file and then using readlines(), so i find your hint very useful and will sure try to do it like this. I took a look at the PIL source code, and it passes the encoding option to a FreeType primitive, without explaining all the possible choices -however, the default is unicode-. Until now i have found a nice workaround by using an "ASCII Art" font, but i'll try your hint and i hope this can help me to get the program working without having to distribute the special font together. All legit: a website asked for a way to show some ASCII arts ;)